# Overwrite Serilog Sinks via Json Configuration

Tags: serilog

I have a Configuration in code:

```
...
config.WriteTo.Console(
                theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] [Pid={ProcessId}] [Td={ThreadId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}");
...
```

this Configuration I would like to overwrite in the JSON Configuration file:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Console"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console","Args":{...}},
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems like it is only possible to ADD Sinks via the Config File. Is there a way to overwrite existing configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code and configuration APIs to Serilog are completely separate, so it's only possible to add sinks via configuration.